# decreasing the size of the expansional panel in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this requirement where I need to decrease the size of the expansion panel when it is open or say expanded.
I looked into the elements and styles tab but I see that we need to overwrite the styles.
Anyone who has handled this case?

Here is the to the sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/yp9lmvwo1x
I basically want to decrease the size of the blue part in the first accordion.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using `withStyles` HOC provided by material-ui.

```
const CustomExpansionPanel = withStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  expanded: {
    height: "110px"
  }
}))(ExpansionPanel);
```

However you will also have to tweak the inner `ExpansionPanelSummary` and `ExpansionPanelDetails` if you are using them.

Here is a working sample for above : https://codesandbox.io/s/nr65w2qwp4